# fastest way to iterate in python

Tags: python, numpy, pyopengl

I've never had to concern myself with this problem so far but now I need to use some large number of vertices that need to be buffered by PyOpenGL and it seems like the python iteration is the bottleneck. Here is the situation. I have an array of 3D points `vertices`, and at each step I have to compute a 4D array of colors for each vertices. My approach so far is:

```
upper_border = len(self.vertices) / 3
#Only generate at first step, otherwise use old one and replace values
if self.color_array is None:
     self.color_array = numpy.empty(4 * upper_border)  

for i in range(upper_border):
     #Obtain a color between a start->end color
     diff_activity = (activity[i] - self.min) / abs_diff  
     clr_idx = i * 4
     self.color_array[clr_idx] = start_colors[0] + diff_activity * end_colors[0]
     self.color_array[clr_idx + 1] = start_colors[1] + diff_activity * end_colors[1]
     self.color_array[clr_idx + 2] = start_colors[2] + diff_activity * end_colors[2]
     self.color_array[clr_idx + 3] = 1
```

Now I don't think there's anything else I can do to eliminate the operations from each step of the loop, but I'm guessing there has to be a more optimal performance way to do that loop. I'm saying that because in javascript for example, the same calculus produces a 9FPS while in Python I'm only getting 2-3 FPS.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: if you are using python 2, replace `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: If the iteration really is the bottleneck, one possibility might be to recode the loop in Cython: http://cython.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make this code faster, you need to "vectorise" it:  replace all explicit Python loops with implicit loops, using NumPy's broadcasting rules.  I can try and give a vectorised version of your loop:

```py
if self.color_array is None:
     self.color_array = numpy.empty((len(activity), 4))
diff_activity = (activity - self.min) / abs_diff
self.color_array[:, :3] = (start_colors + 
                           diff_activity[:, numpy.newaxis] + 
                           end_colors)
self.color_array[:, 3] = 1
```

Note that I had to do a lot of guessing, since I'm not sure what all your variables are and what the code is supposed to do, so I can't guarantee this code runs.  I turned `color_array` into a two-dimensional array, since this seems more appropriate.  This probably requires changes in other parts of the code (or you need to flatten the array again).

I assume that `self.min` and `abs_diff` are scalars and all other names reference NumPy arrays of the following shapes:

```py
activity.shape == (len(vertices) // 3,)
start_colors.shape == (3,)
end_colors.shape == (3,)
```

It also looks as if `vertices` is a one-dimensional array and should be a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks, starting from this suggestion I actually managed to use numpy to make the whole loop just some matrix multiplications and that actually got it to run aproximately 6 times faster.

Answer (score 6):

1. First of all : **profile your code** with [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html)
2. You should use [xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of range
3. You should avoid to recall `self.color_array` 4 times on each loop, try to create a local variable before the loop, and use it into the loop : `local_array = self.color_array`
4. try to pre-compute the `start_colors[N]` and `end_colors[N]` : `start_color_0 = start_colors[0]`
5. try to use [list.extend()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=extend) to reduce lines in loop :

   ```
   local_array.extend([
      start_colors_0 + diff_activity * end_colors_0,
      start_colors_1 + diff_activity * end_colors_1,
      start_colors_2 + diff_activity * end_colors_2,
      1
   ])
   ```

Comment: note that using cProfile is as easy as doing `python -mcProfile <your_program.py>`